# Chrome Extension VueJS : how to create overlay over web page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vuejs2

I’m creating a Chrome Extension App with VueJS. With google chrome extensions you can push some HTML in other web page, I want to do the same thing with my VueJS App. I’ve created a file that is supposed to push my app in the body of any page but it doesn't work.

There is the file :

```
import App from './App'

const element = document.querySelector('body').firstChild
const anchor = document.createElement('DIV')
anchor.insertBefore(element)

new Vue({
    el: anchor,
    render: h => h(App)
})
```

I've also my popup.js who as the same utilities than main.js. This file is for the creation of my app, there it is :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router/index'
import { fb } from './firebase/init'

let app = null;


fb.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => {
  if(!app){
    app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router,

      render: h => h(App)
    })
  }
})
```

And there is my content-script in the manifest.json :

```
{
  "name": "******",
  "description": "VueJS Extension",
  "version": null,
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "128": "icons/******.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "*****",
    "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "identity"
  ],
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "**************",
    "scopes": [
      "https://apis.google.com"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["print.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

If someone have any clue, it would be cool ;)

Comment: To add content to a web page you need a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). In that content script you can either add a DOM element or add an iframe that points to your extension's app.html with Vue inside. Look for tutorials that use the second approach (google terms: VueJS iframe web_accessible_resources).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've forgot to put my manifest.json in my question... so I put it back. And content script don't work and I don't know why.

Comment: `anchor.insertBefore(element)` ... which is equivalent to `anchor.appendChild(element)` .... so you're taking the first child of body (document.body by the way) and inserting into a div you created, that doesn't exist in the DOM? ... documentation for insertBefore ... `parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode);` ... so you want `document.body.insertBefore(anchor, element)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is this

```
const element = document.querySelector('body').firstChild
const anchor = document.createElement('DIV')
anchor.insertBefore(element)
```

now, according to documentation ..., insertBefore works like this

```
parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode);
```

so, your `parentNode` is a newly created node that isn't in the DOM

your `newNode` is the body's first child

and reference node is null (so, you're inserting the node at the end)

you're effectively doing this

```
const element = document.body.firstChild
const anchor = document.createElement('DIV')
anchor.appendChild(element)
```

what you probably wanted to do was

```
const element = document.body.firstChild
const anchor = document.createElement('DIV')
document.body.insertBefore(anchor, element)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it !